# Change Read Status in Inbox (On My Computer) through applescript

Tags: macos, outlook, applescript, outlook-2011

I have a rule to autocopy every message received from a work email to the On My Computer inbox. However, the rule to automatically change its read status to true doesn't work. I took to applescript to see if I could this through here. I've gotten to here but everything I've tried has failed. Here's what I have currently:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
  set srcFolder to mail folder "Inbox" of on my computer
  set allMessages to every message of srcFolder
  repeat with aMessage in allMessages
    set readstatus of aMessage to true
  end repeat
end tell
```

The error is:

> error "Microsoft Outlook got an error: Can't make readstatus of incoming message id 23393 into type specifier." number -1700 from readstatus of incoming message id 23393 to specifier.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The scripting dictionary I have for Outlook (I don't have the application) does not have a property known as `readstatus`. But there is a boolean property `is read`. So doing something like

```
set is read of aMessage to true
```

(in the tell block of course) or something like that might work.